# Compass: Rotate image towards a particular location

Tags: android, location, latitude-longitude, compass

I have a requirement to rotate image arrow to particular location. Here is my current code:

```
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        float azimuth = event.values[0];
        Location currentLoc = getHelper().getCurrentLocation();
        if(currentLoc == null || cardinal == null || cardinal.getLocation() == null) {
            return;
        }

        azimuth = (float) Math.toDegrees(azimuth);
        GeomagneticField geoField = new GeomagneticField(
                (float) currentLoc.getLatitude(),
                (float) currentLoc.getLongitude(),
                (float) currentLoc.getAltitude(),
                System.currentTimeMillis());

        azimuth += geoField.getDeclination(); // converts magnetic north into true north
        float bearing = currentLoc.bearingTo(cardinal.getLocation()); // (it's already in degrees)
        float direction = azimuth - bearing;
        direction = -direction;
        if(compass != null) {
            compass.setDirection(direction);
        }
}
```

And here is my custom imageview:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) { //
    int height = this.getHeight();  //
    int width = this.getWidth();

    canvas.rotate(direction, width / 2, height / 2); //
    super.onDraw(canvas); //
}
```

And here is the arrow image that I am using:
[image]

This code does not work at all. Can anybody points me where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself. I am posting the answer for other guys who are looking for same solution: Here is the updated code:

```
    float azimuth = event.values[0];
        Location currentLoc = getHelper().getCurrentLocation();
        if(currentLoc == null || cardinal == null || cardinal.getLocation() == null) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            GeomagneticField geoField = new GeomagneticField(
                    Double.valueOf(currentLoc.getLatitude()).floatValue(),
                    Double.valueOf(currentLoc.getLongitude()).floatValue(),
                    Double.valueOf(currentLoc.getAltitude()).floatValue(),
                    System.currentTimeMillis() );

            float myBearing = currentLoc.bearingTo(cardinal.getLocation());

            azimuth += geoField.getDeclination();
            azimuth = (myBearing - azimuth) * -1;
            azimuth = normalizeDegree(azimuth);
//            compass.updateValues(-azimuth);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(compass != null) {
            compass.setDirection(-azimuth);
        }
```

Comment: Can you post  sample code for this with activity and xml code?